# Laravel 7.x cannot connect to Oracle or Sqlsrv

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel 5.8, connect to oracle and sqlsrv without problem.
site: xxx.local

Today I installed a new laravel 7.16.1, both oracle and sqlsrv cannot work.
But mysql is ok.
site: xxxdev.local

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1    xxx.local
127.0.0.1    xxxdev.local

oracle package: yajra/laravel-oci8
sqlsrv package: i dont remember using such package

The php version and extension should be ok. Because the two websites use the same php version and php files.

oracle error message: ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure
sqlsrv error message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream (SQL: select * from Employee)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Codes\php\xxx.local\httpdocs\public"
    ServerName xxx.local
    ErrorLog "logs/xxx.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxx.local-access.log" common
  FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "D:/Servers/php/php-7.3.7-Win32-VC15-x64"
  FcgidWrapper "D:/Servers/php/php-7.3.7-Win32-VC15-x64/php-cgi.exe" .php
    Alias "/storage/image" "D:\Codes\php\xxx.local\httpdocs\storage\app\public\image"
  
  <Directory "D:\Codes\php\xxx.local\httpdocs">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Indexes
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin arhatron@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Codes\php\xxx.local\devhttp\public"
    ServerName xxxdev.local
    ErrorLog "logs/xxxdev.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxxdev.local-access.log" common
  FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "D:/Servers/php/php-7.3.7-Win32-VC15-x64"
  FcgidWrapper "D:/Servers/php/php-7.3.7-Win32-VC15-x64/php-cgi.exe" .php
    Alias "/storage/image" "D:\Codes\php\xxx.local\devhttp\storage\app\public\image"
  
  <Directory "D:\Codes\php\xxx.local\devhttp">
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Indexes
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my problem. No all work.

**Oracle**
I edited config/oracle.php, which is generated by the yajra package.  But another file config/database.php also should add oracle in connections, this doesn't exist in laravel.

```
    'connections' => [
...
        'oracle' => [
            'driver'         => 'oracle',
            'tns'            => env('DB_TNS', ''),
            'host'           => env('DB_HOST_ORA', ''),
            'port'           => env('DB_PORT_ORA', '1521'),
            'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE_ORA', ''),
            'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME_ORA', ''),
            'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD_ORA', ''),
            'charset'        => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
            'prefix'         => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'prefix_schema'  => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
            'edition'        => env('DB_EDITION', 'ora$base'),
            'server_version' => env('DB_SERVER_VERSION', '11g'),
            'options' => [PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT =>1,]
        ],
```

**SQLSRV**

```
    'connections' => [
...
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SQLSRV', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SQLSRV', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SQLSRV', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SQLSRV', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SQLSRV', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

        'oracle' => [
...
```

The env variables are changed. Maybe I changed last year to make it more readable, and I forgot.